# In JavaEE using asynchronous events logs "No valid EE environment for injection of ObserverClass"

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi, payara, java-ee-8

I have implemented a REST endpoint in JavaEE that fires an asynchronous event to trigger a process each time the endpoint is used by a user.

This all works as intended and the process is triggered asynchronously, but results in a `SEVERE` level log: `No valid EE environment for injection of TagsProcessor` and I do not understand why.

Is this a bug in Payara? Or am I doing something wrong?

Here is an example implementation:

Rest endpoint where the event is fired on each login:

```
@Path("auth")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@RequestScoped
public class AuthenticationResource {

    @POST
    @Path("request-jwt")
    @PermitAll
    @Timed(name = "appV2RequestJwt", absolute = true)
    public Response appRequestJwt(RefreshRequest refreshRequest) {
        JwtResponse dto;

        try {
            dto = authenticationProcessor.appRequestJwt(refreshRequest);

            //Fire asynchronous event
            calculateTagsEvent.fireAsync(new CalculateTagsEvent(refreshRequest.getUsername()));

            return Response.ok(dto).build();
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "Could not request jwt: {}", exception.getMessage());
            dto = new JwtResponse(null, INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            return Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).entity(dto).build();
        }
    }

}
```

Observer class:

```
@RequestScoped
public class TagsProcessor {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(TagsProcessor.class.getName());

    @Inject
    private BeanController beanController;


    //Observe asynchronous event
    public void manageCalculateTagsEvent(@ObservesAsync CalculateTagsEvent event) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.WARNING, "Event observed");
        beanController.create(new SomeBean());
    }
}
```

This results in the logs:

```
[#|2022-08-17T06:39:39.461+0000|SEVERE|Payara 5.201||_ThreadID=473;_ThreadName=payara-executor-service-task;_TimeMillis=1660718379461;_LevelValue=1000;| No valid EE environment for injection of TagsProcessor|#]

[#|2022-08-17T06:39:39.473+0000|WARNING|Payara 5.201|TagsProcessor|_ThreadID=473;_ThreadName=payara-executor-service-task;_TimeMillis=1660718379473;_LevelValue=900;| Event observed|#]
```

So it's working as intended, but is giving me the warning about the injection...

Comment: I strongly believe that the problem is that `TagsProcessor` is `@RequestScoped`. I believe that the request scope is NOT ACTIVE in the threads that handle the asynchronous event firing. (This is reasonable because the request scope is naturally tied to the thread handling the response; this thread may well have finished processing - and killed the request scope - while the async event threads are still executing.) Can you try making the `TagsProcessor` `@ApplicationScoped`?

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos I thought so too and have tried various scopes, but they all carry the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment I did try various scopes but in the end it's supposed to be a `@Stateless` EJB that can be spawned from a pool without being attached to the client's state.